# How ASP.NET Web Pages Threading / Multi Tasking Works for Single user?

Tags: asp.net

This Might be a very basic Questing. (URGENT)

I have a Web application with multiple pages.

When a user is Logged in using Visual Studio(Development) / IIS (Production )

If the user have opened a Page 1 from home page which is long running process (Lets say few minutes)

Can the same user open Page 2 from home page while Page 1 is still running.

There is no connection between Page1 and Page 2.

Remember I am talking about the same user in the same machine.

Does ASP.NET takes care of this MultiThreading by default for above situation?

Or I Should create Separate Thread for each page?

I my case I not able to open the second page still the first page is Finished.

Please shed me some light.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, if a user is opening Page 1 (which may take a long time to render), other users, or even the same user, can still open other pages in the application at the same time* (including Page 1 again).

(*) *Unless database locking or some other explicit mechanism prevents this, however you have to try fairly hard to get this to happen*

Comment: I am using different database connections for different page. And When i Click the button for Page 2 on the Home page it is not even hitting page init or Page load. No errors  no progress until the first page is finished. IS there any setting i need to enable to make this happen? Please let me know.